# Testing android with Firebase

Tags: android, unit-testing, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-espresso

I'm working on Android project and some time ago I decided to use Firebase as it seemed just what I was looking for. And indeed it fits my needs pretty good, but testing functionality that depends on Firebase turned out to be a nightmare to me. There is no official mock, so the only solution I found was to create 2 Firebase projects (prod and dev instance) and configure build types to use different projects for different build variants. Technically it works, but has a few drawbacks

- My tests are no longer independent from each other as they share the same database and authentication context.
- Network operations are time consuming. Especially hard to test with Espresso as I never know how much time I need to wait to receive data.
- It's difficult to setup & cleanup environment before and after test.
- Asynchronous approach doesn't let me create handy mocks for my DAO object as I can't feed mocked data to ValueEventListener.

I don't expect to find a panacea here, but I'm sure that I'm not the only one struggling with these problems, so maybe someone has found how to bypass at least some of them? I would also appreciate any ideas or links that can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's [standard and recommended practice](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/organizing-your-firebase-enabled-android-app-builds.html) to create different projects for different environments, such as a dev and prod.

If you need to fully isolate your tests, look into [Android Test Orchestrator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner.html#using-android-test-orchestrator).

It's generally a bad practice to have your Espresso test depend on a certain amount of time for network operations to complete.  Espresso will wait for changes to your UI in response to changes (onView does this), so Espresso tests should be driven by what the user would see in the UI.

You can most definitely mock Firebase APIs.  You might want to ask a more specific question here with your code that doesn't work the way you want.